# Difference between skbuff frags and frag_list

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, fragmentation

The *sk_buff* has two places where it can store the next fragmentation data:

```
skb_shinfo(head)->frag_list 
skb_shinfo(head)->frags[]
```

What are the differences between these two ways to handle fragmentation?

Comment: *skb* = [socket buffer](http://vger.kernel.org/~davem/skb.html)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Both are used for different cases.

**frags[]**

When your device supports scatter-gather I/O, and you want it to do the combining of data, etc., you can populate the `frags[]` structure starting with the second fragment till the nth fragment. The first fragment is always specified by the `data` and `tail` pointers. The rest of the fragments are filled in the `frags[]` structure. If you don't use scatter gather, this variable is empty.

**frag_list**

This is the list of IP fragments. This will be filled during `ip_push_pending_frames`.

Say your `sk_buffs` are in this arrangement,

```
sk_buff0->next = sk_buff1
sk_buff1->next = sk_buff2
...
sk_buffn-1->next = sk_buffn
```

After `ip_push_pending_frames` is called

```
sk_buff0->frag_list = sk_buff1
sk_buff1->next = sk_buff2
...
sk_buffn-1->next = sk_buffn
```

Simply put

- `frags[]` are for scatter-gather I/O buffers
- `frag_list` is for IP fragments

Comment: Thank a lot @bjxt! your explanation is very clear. Now I know how different they are

Answer (score 5):

**skb_shinfo(head)->frags[]**

If the [NIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_interface_controller) supports SG I/O, [__ip_append_data](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/ipv4/ip_output.c#L833) will copy user space data to skb_shinfo(head)->frags. The NIC driver (e.g., ixgbe_add_rx_frag) can also use these frags[] to carry the received network traffic; please note that every content in frags[] is a part of a complete packet. A complete packet consists of all frags[] + (skb->data ~ skb->tail).

**skb_shinfo(head)->frag_list**

This member is not used by IP fragmentation directly.
In __ip_make_skb(), the frag_list is used to collect all [skbs](http://vger.kernel.org/%7Edavem/skb.html) from sk->sk_write_queue; some NIC drivers also use this frag_list for carrying a packet to the upper network stack. Every content/skb in frag_list is also not a **complete** packet; tcp_v4_send_ack -> ip_send_unicast_reply -> ip_push_pending_frames -> ip_finish_skb -> __ip_make_skb;